# Update gRaphael line chart column values

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael

I have a gRaphael line chart which I update on click using the below function, the problem I have is that when I try to set the column values, it does not take effect. Like so...

```
         var iniGraph   = Raphael("graph"),
        chart = iniGraph.linechart(
                0,5,
                $('#graph').width(),$('#graph').height(),
                xVals,yVals,
                { nostroke: false, symbol: ["circle",""], width: 1.5, smooth: true, shade: true, colors: ['#008cc2', '#7500c6'] }
         ).hoverColumn(function(){
                // AFTER UPDATE THESE VALUES STILL REMAIN UNCHANGED
                console.log(this.values[0]+" | "+this.values[1]);
         },function(){
                // do nothing
         });


    function animateChart(graph,curChart,newX,newY)
    {
        // generate the new chart
        var newChart = graph.linechart(
                0,5,
                $('#graph').width(),$('#graph').height(),
                newX,
                newY,
                { nostroke: false, symbol: ["circle",""], width: 1.5, smooth: true, shade: true, colors: ['#008cc2', '#7500c6'] }
         );

        // THIS DOES NOT WORK, THE ORIGINAL VALUES REMAIN AFTER UPDATE 
        curChart.eachColumn(function(){
            this.values[0] = 12341234;
            this.values[1] = 12341234;
        });

        // animate the symbols
        $.each(curChart.symbols[0],function(i,symbol){
            symbol.animate({ cx: newChart.symbols[0][i].attr("cx"),cy: newChart.symbols[0][i].attr("cy") }, 200);
        });

        // animate the lines
        $.each(curChart.lines,function(i,line){
            line.animate({ path: newChart.lines[i].attr("path") }, 200);
        });

        // remove the new chart
        newChart.remove();
    }
```

I create an initial graph and create the line chart, I then use the `animateChart` function to animate/update the line chart to it's new values, the problem I am running into is that on hover, the values remain unchanged after the `animateChart` function has run, so I am stuck with the initial values of the chart, which is not ideal, as I have to get the column values to update to the new values I specify.

So basically, how can I update the column values when I animate/update the line chart?

I'm kinda at the end of my rope... thanks.